how do you sort column names in Date in descending order in pandas
I have this DataFrame:
Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier     Date            
Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-05-09
Server1   wan1         100     50       Sprint      2024-06-21
Server1   wan1         100     30       Verizon     2024-07-01  
Server2   wan1         100     90       ATT         2024-05-01
Server2   wan1         100     88       Sprint      2024-06-02
Server2   wan1         100     22       Verizon     2024-07-19 

I need to convert Date field to this format 1-May, 2-Jun, 19-July, place them on each column in descending order. In this to look like this:
  Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier     1-July 9-May  21-Jun          
    Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT        80    50     30    

I tried this:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%b')
df['is'] = df['Band_In'] / df['Speed'] * 100
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Node', 'Interface', 'carrier'], columns='Date', values='is').reset_index()

I need Date values in the column names to be sorted in descending order 9-May 21-Jun 1-July.
Any ideas how?

Keep them as date times, sort them, and at the end cast to string with your wanted format

Don't convert your dates to string until after the pivot_table, so can do so easily with rename:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['is'] = df['Band_In'] / df['Speed'] * 100

out = (df.pivot_table(index=['Node', 'Interface', 'carrier'],
                      columns='Date', values='is')
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strftime('%-d-%b'))
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )

Output:
      Node Interface  carrier  1-May  9-May  2-Jun  21-Jun  1-Jul  19-Jul
0  Server1      wan1      ATT    NaN   80.0    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
1  Server1      wan1   Sprint    NaN    NaN    NaN    50.0    NaN     NaN
2  Server1      wan1  Verizon    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   30.0     NaN
3  Server2      wan1      ATT   90.0    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
4  Server2      wan1   Sprint    NaN    NaN   88.0     NaN    NaN     NaN
5  Server2      wan1  Verizon    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    22.0


import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Node": ["Server1", "Server1", "Server1", "Server2", "Server2", "Server2"],
    "Interface": ["wan1", "wan1", "wan1", "wan1", "wan1", "wan1"],
    "Speed": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
    "Band_In": [80, 50, 30, 90, 88, 22],
    "carrier": ["ATT", "Sprint", "Verizon", "ATT", "Sprint", "Verizon"],
    "Date": ["2024-05-09", "2024-06-21", "2024-07-01", "2024-05-01", "2024-06-02", "2024-07-19"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%b')
df['is'] = df['Band_In'] / df['Speed'] * 100

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(values= 'is', index=['Node', 'Interface', 'carrier'],
                          columns = 'Date', fill_value = 0).reset_index()
print(pivot_df.to_string())
'''
Date     Node Interface  carrier  01-Jul  01-May  02-Jun  09-May  19-Jul  21-Jun
0     Server1      wan1      ATT     0.0     0.0     0.0    80.0     0.0     0.0
1     Server1      wan1   Sprint     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    50.0
2     Server1      wan1  Verizon    30.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3     Server2      wan1      ATT     0.0    90.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
4     Server2      wan1   Sprint     0.0     0.0    88.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5     Server2      wan1  Verizon     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    22.0     0.0
'''

